# Why python code showing error while executing the below code? here variable declared globally and not taking the value of the global variable

Tags: python

Why python code showing error while executing the below code? here variable  declared globally and not taking the value of the global variable

```
a=7
def fun1(a):
    if a%2==0: return 0
    else: return 1
fun1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `fun1()` to require an argument, and then you called it without giving an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `a` as a variable, but your function definition requires an argument which also happens to be called `a`, but is not related to the declared variable.

Two options, you can either pass the variable to the function when calling:

```
a=7 
def fun1(a): 
    if a%2==0: 
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1

fun1(a)
```

Or you can declare `a` as `global` within the function to access it without having to pass it as an argument when calling the function:

```
a=7 
def fun1(): 
    global a
    if a%2==0: 
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1

fun1()
```